# How do I make sure downloaded content and my list have matching indexes?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am downloading files from a server and placing them in a list, after doing some manipulation to them.

How do I set those files to be in the correct index from which the source url came from?

For example, I have

```
  List<myCustomObject> downloadedContentContainers {get;set;}
  myCustomObject contains a property downloadURL
  myCustomOBject also contains a property called downloadedByteArray
```

Each item in the downloadContentContainers holds the url to get the downloadedContent, when the download and manipulation process is finished, I want the result to be placed in a property of myCustomObject, but in the correct index of downloadedContentContainers.

In short, I want the results of the myCustomObject.downloadUrl to be inserted into myCustomObject.downloadedByteArray

How do I do this?

My main obstancles are lambda and scope outputs, using foreach for lists, and a lack of an index, as well as large file sizes and asynchronicity.

Comment: You have not given enough detail for anyone to be able to answer your question. What are you exact inputs and what is your desired output?

Comment: @ColinE Thanks, sorry seems there was some issue with the code block, and I've also added more information.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is you don't have access to the index information of that particular item in the async method that does the downloading. You should put the download logic into myCustomObject class, so you can set its downloadedByteArray from there.

Comment: @mostruash Thank you, I'm feeling stupid now.  Is that a common C# pattern, and if it is, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a common C# pattern or not but if you are using an asynchronous method and if you need to change some properties of an object, the easiest way is to put that method into that particular class. 
If you (don't want to)/(can't) do that, somehow you need to find a reference to that object, sometimes there is a way to put it into event args, or you can access it via event sender object.
Thus in your case  you should put the download logic into myCustomObject class, so you can set its downloadedByteArray from there.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know C# well enough to know how to pass those args into the async events.  It feels like a trail of spaghetti to me, and when I have tried I have hit lambda and scope issues.  If you do, I can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: It depends on the type of EventHandler and EventArgs you are using with your download logic. I.e. if you are using WebClient's OpenReadAsync method, you can pass an object: OpenReadAsync(uri, obj). And in the event handler you can access it with e.UserState.